# How do I set the kernel size of keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM class?

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm

I'm competing in a NLP Kaggle competition. I don't have much experience with NLP machine learning. Does a LSTM even have a kernel size?

Answer (score 0):

LSTM's do not have kernel size, but have other parameters that should be set, mainly units. Take a look at this [link](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) if you have not already to get some basic understanding of how they work.

You can also leverage [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) from non-programming questions.